# Find-replace-regexp with elisp replacement not working correctly

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I have a string in a buffer `"THIS_IS_A_TEST"` (the quotes are part of the string).

I want to turn this in to `"ThisIsATest"`. I'm attempting to do this using a `query-replace-regexp` where I substitute `\(\w+\)_?` with `\,(capitalize \1)`. However, the upcased words are not being capitalized.

Running `M-c` (`capitalize-word`) on any of those words works fine, and if my test string is changed to  `"this_is_a_test"`, then I get the desired result (`"ThisIsATest"`).

What's going wrong? Is this a bug in capitalize?

(Note that this still happens without an init file loaded)

Answer (score 2):

It works for me if I set `case-replace` to `nil`.  I'm not sure why this doesn't do the same thing for the lower case string, though...

Comment: For me it works fine for both (lowercase and uppercase tests). Note, however, that there are *two* variables that govern the behavior here: `case-replace` and **`case-fold-search`**.

Comment: I haven't modified either case-replace or case-fold-search but I would not expect `(capitalize "FOO"`) to have different semantics depending on whether I'm using it in a search or not. If this is the 'expected' behaviour, rather than my misuse of it (somehow), then I propose that this is a bug.

Comment: MrBones: Note that `capitalize` isn't doing anything unexpected (if you type `?` for help during the replacement query, it will show you that the call to capitalize returned the expected value). The behaviour here is a question of what Emacs does when the replacement word is identical, save for case, to the original (or a case-modified original); and the variables mentioned control that behaviour.

Comment: So capitalize is doing capitalizing, but case-replace combined with case-fold-search is undoing it? IMO, that's a bug